# Android RelativeLayout does layout_alignTop include padding / margin?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to design a keypad with RelativeLayout.
Each time I try to use  layout_alignTop or bottom or Right... I see that blocks are not perfectly aligned as if android would take into account the padding or the margin for on of the aligned objects.
Here my "Go" key spans overs two lines and I can't get it well aligned. Same with my top "X" key.

Keyboard with Go Key not aligned

[image: Keyboard with Go Key not aligned]

Here is my layout :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/keybord_text_label"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kb_b1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_text_value"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keybord_text_label"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kb_b1"
       />

        <Button
            android:text="X"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_bdel"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/keyboard_text_value"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/keyboard_text_value"
            />


        <Button
            android:text="1"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyboard_text_value"/>
        <Button
            android:text="2"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyboard_text_value"/>
        <Button
            android:text="3"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyboard_text_value"/>

        <Button
        android:text="4"
        style="@style/keyboard_btn"
        android:id="@+id/kb_b4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"/>
        <Button
            android:text="5"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"/>
        <Button
            android:text="6"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"/>


        <Button
                android:text="7"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b4"/>
            <Button
                android:text="8"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b8"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b4"/>
            <Button
                android:text="9"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b9"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b4"/>

        <Button
                android:text="0"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b0"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b7"
                />
            <Button
                android:text="+"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_bplus"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b0"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b7"
                />
            <Button
                android:text="-"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_bminus"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_bplus"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b7"
                />

        <Button
            android:text="X"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_bback"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bdel" />

        <Button
            android:text="GO"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_bgo"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/kb_b6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/kb_bminus" />





    <Button
        android:text=".00"
        style="@style/keyboard_btn"
        android:id="@+id/kb_b00"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b0"
         />


    <Button
        android:text=".25"
        style="@style/keyboard_btn"
        android:id="@+id/kb_b25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b00"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bplus"
        />
    <Button
        android:text=".50"
        style="@style/keyboard_btn"
        android:id="@+id/kb_b50"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b25"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bminus"
      />

    <Button
        android:text=".75"
        style="@style/keyboard_btn"
        android:id="@+id/kb_b75"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b50"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bgo"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my style

```
 <style name="keyboard_btn" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/keyboard_btn</item>
</style>
```

I have also tried TableLayout and GridLayout be it's even worse.

Help would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `GridLayout` and setting the go button to span multiple rows?

Comment: Yes I've tried both grid layout and tablelayout (with horizontal Go key) and found it was even more difficult to have anything looking nice.

Comment: it looks like it's aligning the margin to the top of the other buttons, have you tried `android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"` in the GO button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I believe using `layout_below` and `layout_above` might work better:

```
    <Button
        android:text="GO"
        style="@style/keyboard_btn"
        android:id="@+id/kb_bgo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b6"
        android:layout_above="@+id/kb_b00" />
```

Comment: Thank. Works better.

Comment: glad to hear it, don't forget to select the answer that "worked for you"

Comment: @Nathalie this is not how Stackoverflow works. If this answer helped you, mark it as the accepted answer instead of creating your own answer and marking it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much it solved my problem.

In case it can help somebody :

Here is the result

[Keyboard all well aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDZA4.png)

Here is the code

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <!-- TEXTBOX -->
        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/keybord_text_label"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kb_b1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/keyboard_text_value"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keybord_text_label"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kb_b1"
       />

        <Button
            android:text="X"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_bdel"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_above="@+id/kb_sep"
            />


        <!-- SEPARATOR -->
        <View
            android:id="@+id/kb_sep"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/keyboard_text_value"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/kb_bdel"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kb_bdel"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/kb_b1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kb_b1"
            android:background="#ffffffff"/>


        <!-- LINE 1 -->
        <Button
            android:text="1"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_sep"/>
        <Button
            android:text="2"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_sep"/>
        <Button
            android:text="3"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_sep"/>

        <Button
            android:text="<"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_bback"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_sep" />

        <!-- LINE 2 -->
        <Button
            android:text="4"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"/>

        <Button
            android:text="5"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b5"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"/>

        <Button
            android:text="6"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_b6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b1"/>

        <Button
            android:text="GO"
            style="@style/keyboard_btn"
            android:id="@+id/kb_bgo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bback"
            android:layout_above="@+id/kb_b75"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b6"/>

        <!-- LINE 3 -->
        <Button
                android:text="7"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b4"/>
            <Button
                android:text="8"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b8"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b7"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b4"/>
            <Button
                android:text="9"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b9"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b4"/>

        <!-- LINE 4 -->
        <Button
                android:text="0"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b0"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b7"
                />
            <Button
                android:text="+"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_bplus"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b0"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b7"
                />
            <Button
                android:text="-"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_bminus"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_bplus"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b7"
                />

        <!-- LINE 5 -->
            <Button
                android:text=".00"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b00"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_b0"
                 />


            <Button
                android:text=".25"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b25"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b00"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bplus"
                />
            <Button
                android:text=".50"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b50"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b25"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bminus"
              />

            <Button
                android:text=".75"
                style="@style/keyboard_btn"
                android:id="@+id/kb_b75"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kb_b50"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kb_bminus"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>
```